# cannot remove package inted

Tags: apt, package-management, inetd

How to remove inted package?

if I try

```
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove inetd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'inetd' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
```

But I have it installed (I can for example see its man page `man inetd` and even run it):

```
$ inetd
inetd: non-root must specify a config file
```

so how to remove this package?

Comment: /usr/sbin/inetd
/sbin/inetd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package name in Ubuntu is `openbsd-inetd`.

```
$ apt-file search bin/inetd
openbsd-inetd: /usr/sbin/inetd
rlinetd: /usr/sbin/inetd2rlinetd
```

`inetd` is a virtual package which explains why you were able to remove it yet still it did not remove that binary.

Comment: what is virtual package?

Comment: It's a generic package name which multiple packages can provide, and then anything that depends on that functionality can be satisfied by any of them. So in this case the package ```openbsd-inetd``` provides the virtual package ```inetd``` so that anything that wants that functionality would be satisfied. But the virtual package ```inetd``` does not contain any binaries itself, which is why you removing it did not get rid of the binary. https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-virtual-pkg